# pass data while loading to the page loaded by ajax

Tags: ajax

I am loading page url.php and want to pass $x to url.php.

```
var myid=mydata.id;
   $.ajax({
                         url:'url.php'
                         ,async:     true
                         ,cache:     false
                         , data : 'post_field=' + myid
                         ,dataType:  'html'
                         ,success:   function(data){
                           $('body').html(data);
                           FB.XFBML.parse();
                         }
                       }
                             );
```

at url.php

```
<?php
$myid=$_POST[myid];
echo "myID is : <br>";
echo myid;
?>
```

What's wrong here?

Gives errror:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant myid - assumed 'myid' in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/ec2/url.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: myid in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/ec2/url.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
myID is : <br><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant myid - assumed 'myid' in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/FB/ec2/url.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
myid<html>
```

Comment: what is `$x`??Is it a php variable?

Comment: @Joke_Sense10: consider it JS var!

Answer (score 1):

for passing post value... use

```
$.ajax({
                         url:'url.php'
                         ,async:     true
                         ,cache:     false
                         ,dataType:  'html'
                         , data : 'post_field=' + $x  
                         ,success:   function(data){
                           $('body').html(data);
                           FB.XFBML.parse();
                         }
                       }
                             );

             }
```

if you are using jquery and want to post form input , you can do

```
var data = $('#my_form').serialize();

$.ajax({
                         url:'url.php'
                         ,async:     true
                         ,cache:     false
                         ,dataType:  'html'
                         , data : data  
                         ,success:   function(data){
                           $('body').html(data);
                           FB.XFBML.parse();
                         }
                       }
                             );

                 }
```

Comment: Thanks , using jquery can I post value of `x`?

Comment: you have a typo in you  code echo myid; should be echo $myid; at url.php  you get the value like this $_POST['post_field'];

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var formData = $('#formId').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url.php',
    async: true,
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('body').html(data);
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
});
```

Comment: `var formData = $('#formId').serialize();` can you please explain this!

Comment: Your comment will be submitted via a `form`, so `#formId` will be your form id